# Flow covariant property in an array

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If I use something like this

```
type T0 = {p0: string, +p1?: string};
type T1 = {p0: string, p1: string};

function F0(a: T0) {}
function F1(a: T1) {
    F0(a);
}
```

[flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqADGALxgDeOxAXGAM4YBOAlgHYDmANGANQ4AjAH56TNlwC+Abky4ChQeSo0xLDjzBC1EzjPRQAruwDGGVnHZgAYsQAUAQ3okAlFUmojp85ZuDHzoJulKhgYACQto4uspJAA)

all is ok: T0.p1 is covariant and no errors are there.

But. If I need as argument an array of the types

```
type T0 = {p0: string, +p1?: string};
type T1 = {p0: string, p1: string};

function F0(a: T0[]) {}
function F1(a: T1[]) {
    F0(a);
}
```

[flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqADGALxgDeOxAXGAM4YBOAlgHYDmANGANQ4AjAH56TNlwC+Abky4ChQeSo0xLDjzBC1EzjPRQAruwDGGVnHZgAYsQAUAQ3okA2gF0AlFUmojp85Y2go7Ogu5elKhgYACQto4espJAA)

It complains for 'Covariant property `p1` incompatible with invariant use'.
And I have no idea why it happens

Comment: Why not add the js here as well?

Comment: Sagar, I did, sorry

Comment: That's interesting, considering `F1` can take `T1` and you can pass `F0([a])` which makes the argument `T1[]` and doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type signature there would be nothing stopping you from doing

```
function F0(a: T0[]) {
  a.push({ p0: "" });
}
```

which is valid in the type signature of `F0` but invalid in the type signature of `F1`.

This leaves you with two options.

Use a covariant array type `$ReadOnlyArray`, so Flow knows you won't be adding items to the array:

```
type T0 = {p0: string, +p1?: string};
type T1 = {p0: string, p1: string};

function F0(a: $ReadOnlyArray<T0>) {}
function F1(a: T1[]) {
    F0(a);
}
```

Let the types from `F1` flow through into `F0` with a generic, so Flow knows the actual type of the object.

```
type T0 = {p0: string, +p1?: string};
type T1 = {p0: string, p1: string};

function F0<T: T0>(a: Array<T>) {}
function F1(a: T1[]) {
    F0(a);
}
```